# A strange error occurs while my Spring MVC application is starting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

Below is the error info printed on the console:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected raw type form of org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$Match
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected raw type form of org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$Match
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.fromType(JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.java:71)
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.fromTypes(JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.java:119)
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.fromType(JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.java:73)
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.fromTypes(JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.java:119)
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15GenericSignatureInformationProvider.getGenericParameterTypes(Java15GenericSignatureInformationProvider.java:48)
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionBasedResolvedMemberImpl.getGenericParameterTypes(ReflectionBasedResolvedMemberImpl.java:112)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterizedWith(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:791)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterizedWith(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:742)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredMethods(ReferenceType.java:859)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$MethodGetterIncludingItds.get(ResolvedType.java:252)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$MethodGetterIncludingItds.get(ResolvedType.java:250)
at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4$1.hasNext(Iterators.java:213)
at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$6.hasNext(Iterators.java:288)
at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4.hasNext(Iterators.java:230)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.lookupResolvedMember(ResolvedType.java:619)
at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.findSignaturesFromSupertypes(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:192)
at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.findSignaturesFromSupertypes(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:229)
at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.hasNext(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:68)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:317)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:197)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.OrPointcut.matchInternal(OrPointcut.java:56)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.getShadowMatch(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:319)
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:129)
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesMethodExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getShadowMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:416)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:271)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:241)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
... 34 more
```

It is relevant to `RequestMappringHandlerMapping` and Spring AOP.

It is strange because my configuration is not supposed to be relevant to the raw type of AbstractHandlerMethodMapping and the error occured so deeply even in source code of AspectJ.

My application is with Spring 4.3.4, Hibernate 5.2.5, Shiro 1.3.2, AspectJ 1.8.10.

Thanks a lot！

--------------------update------------------

It is unneccessary to provide the configuration of this application because this problem was caused by a bug.

I solved the problem and I added my answer below this question.

Comment: And what do you want from us? You didn't provided any source code, that we could check.

Comment: I am so sorry and ashamed for that, I will supplement other info right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I digged deeplier, Then I knew I was facing a bug  [SPR-15019](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15019). The key exception message is 'Expected raw type form of org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$Match'.

Use Spring 4.3.5 to avoid this problem. Hope you can vote for this question to help whoever is facing this problem to find this solution, because the score of this question is -3 so far, which may affect the ranking. This problem is a tough one.